# Constant value is not printing in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

Hi am passsing my payment transaction id to payment success page,I woluld like to print transaction id to my users .Following is my code in controller

```
if($response["Status"]=="success")
        {
            $clinic =Clinic::find($clinicid);
            $clinic->clinicPub="yes";
            if ($clinic->save()) {
                $payment = new Payment;
                $payment->clinicID=$clinicid;
                $payment->transactionid=$response["Confirmation"];
                $payment->save();
                return view('payment.paymentSuccess')->with('transaction_id', $response["Confirmation"]);
            }
            
        }
```

Am passing `$response["Confirmation"]` with `transactionId` .

Following is the code in my view page

```
<h4>Your subscription is active and you will be charged $29.99 On monthly basis.<i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>{{$transaction_id}}
                        Your Transaction id was {{transaction_id}}
                        <a href="/" class="float-left pt-4">Back to home</a>
```

But my `transaction_id` is not priniting here. It is generating an error

```
Use of undefined constant transaction_id - assumed 'transaction_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the dollar sign on your variable.

`Your Transaction id was {{ $transaction_id }}`

Comment: do i need to use <?php  ?> tags, because it is an html page

Comment: sorry for the late response, but if it is a *.blade.php file it should work as is